# How to create inline link in README.MD in the Azure DevOps Git Repository?

Tags: azure-devops

I try to create an inline link by wrapping link text in brackets [ ], and then wrapping the URL in parentheses ( ).

However I don't get links done. "Preview" and "Contents" show exactly same. What is wrong?

-Development Tool [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-azurefunctions)

Comment: Make sure you don't have whitespace between the closing square bracket `]` and the opening `(`.

Comment: Could you share the markdown code you are writing ?

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with Git. Git itself does nothing special with markdown files.

Comment: @Kenny_I, please check if below answer helps you, if not, please share your code in the README.MD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to create inline link in README.MD in the Azure DevOps Git Repository?

To resolve this issue, you need make sure you are using the standard Markdown link syntax in the Git Repository:

```
[Link Text](Link URL)
```

You could check [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#links) about this.

For example:

```
[TestLink](/TestLibrary/TestLibrary/Class1.cs)

[TestLink2](https://dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/ProjectName/_git/TestRepo?path=%2FREADME.md)
```

[image]

Preview shows:

[image]

Hope this helps.